# What are some seasonings that can spice up a bland frozen chicken alfredo?

Tags: chicken, pasta, spices, italian-cuisine, seasoning

Tonight, the main course is: Red Baron's Chicken Alfredo.

[image]

The problem is that it's a little bland so I'm trying to figure out what the best seasonings will give it more spice, or at least a more intricate taste.  I'm already throwing a lot of salt and pepper in there, what else could one use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, an Alfredo sauce is supposed to taste mostly buttery, with the addition of the umami taste that comes from Parmesan. You could always add spicy stuff to it, but that will change the taste into something completely different. If you want to stay true to the basics of an alfredo dish, try adding a handful of freshly grated Parmesan and (to add to the rich umami taste) some chopped sundried tomatoes. Herbs that go well with this dish are oregano and sage.

Answer (score 3):

- Nutmeg
- Garlic
- Crushed Red Pepper

Answer (score 3):

Tabasco (with filler chars to reach 30)

Comment: I'm more of a Louisiana cayenne pepper sauce guy (French's/Durkee or Crystal), myself, but, yeah, hot sauce is the cure-all for blandness.

Answer (score 0):

-Cayenne red pepper powder (just small amount)

-spinach and broccoli(may not be seasonings but still really good and adds different textures)

-then shredded parmesian, asiago, and ramono cheeses as a topping (creates a nice stickyness without changeing the flavor)

-different meats like shrimp and sea scallops cooked separately then added to the chicken alfreado whith the cayeen red pepper spice was used in an Italian restaurant (again changing the textures)

-last, experiment with different wines and artisan breads to go with it maybe you can try adding those herbs or wine to the sauce ,if you find any you like, without turning dinner into a pass/fail experiment that might be thrown out. ;)

I usually do this with a different frozen chicken alfredo made by bertolli because some of these premade alfredo sauces can't be saved.